# Classes in Subfolder in C#.Net Visual Studio project not seen by code behind files

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a set of C# files for a web application that I've inherited from a developer who's no longer around. I've created a solution in Visual Studio 2010 and added the existing files and subfolders to the solution from source control. One of the subfolders I created is called App_Code and mimics a subfolder that existed in our source control program. Inside this subfolder are a few C# classes. These classes are referenced in code behind files at the root (e.g., ActionPage.aspx.cs: ), but none of the code behind files can find the classes in App_Code. I get the usual error message, "The type or namespace 'ErrorLogger' [one of the classes] could not be found (are you missing a directive or an assembly reference?)" The App_Code subfolder doesn't look like a regular folder. I'm attaching a clip showing what it looks like:

[image: What App_Code subfolder looks like in Visual Studio].

I suspect it's a special Visual Studio folder name. Here's an example of the code in ActionPage that's calling ErrorLogger (and is giving the error message listed above):

```
ErrorLogger Err = new ErrorLogger();
```

And here's what the ErrorLogger class looks like:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

public class ErrorLogger
{

public void Logger(string sPathName, string sErrMsg)
{
    //- <--custom date time stamp & format for easy reading
    string sLogFormat = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString().ToString() + " " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString().ToString() + " ==> ";
    string sYear = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
    string sMonth = DateTime.Now.Month.ToString();
    string sDay = DateTime.Now.Day.ToString();
    //string sErrorTime = sYear+sMonth+sDay;
    string sErrorTime = sMonth + sDay + sYear;
    //- <--Write error to a file
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(sPathName + sErrorTime, true);
    sw.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    sw.WriteLine(sLogFormat + sErrMsg);
    sw.Flush();
    sw.Close();
}
```

}

What am I missing?

Added 2/24/2015: I've found a somewhat unsatisfactory solution: I created a new VS 2010 solution and then chose File->Add->Existing Web Site. I now have the code in a website instead of a web application, but it does compile and run. Short of building the whole thing over again, I think this is the best I can do - unless anyone has any other suggestions.... And I do appreciate all the suggestions, folks, believe me. On a related topic, WHY does File->New->Project from Existing Code not give me the option for a Web Application? Redmond, if you're listening, add that!!

Comment: What namespaces are the classes in? The reason you can't see them is most likely namespace issues.

Comment: look up how to use `namespace` that will make your life a lot easier or look up how to use the `using` clause / statement in your class hearders if you are not familiar with how to find the namespace or default namespace then right click on `AAT`  in the project and select properties to see

Comment: it doesn't look like your class has a namespace, so it will only be accessible to other classes within your project which do not have a namespace declaration.

Comment: Have you tried doing a clean/build on the solution?

Comment: Currently, none of the pages or classes are in namespaces. I've tried adding namespace AAT to the ErrorLogger class and to ActionPage, but it doesn't help.

Comment: @McAden i think that looking at the posted code from the `OP` in all due respect, the issue is and or appears to be a `namespace` Issue

Comment: I have tried a clean/build, but it doesn't help.

Comment: @Melanie you need to add it to the Project..

Comment: You don't"need" namespaces for your app to work, it just things a lot nicer to work with. You mentioned you made the App_Code directory. Working with older Versions of Visual Studio this was problematic sometimes. Have you tried moving the class to the base level to see if it works there?

Comment: also make sure to check if you are using `CodeFile= or CodeBehind=` in the .aspx pages as well namepaces make things easier in my opinion

Comment: @MethodMan - it's currently using CodeFile, but changing it to CodeBehind doesn't help. In your earlier comment, do you mean I need to add the namespace to the Project? How?

Comment: Does anyone know why, in the image, the App_Code folder is grey?

Comment: you have a few issues going on here @Melanie that's why I have asked about the `CodeFile vs CodeBehind` things work a bit differently how ever to add a namespace to your project here are a few link to show 
http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/CSharp/lesson06 || [MSDN C# Understanding and Using NameSpace in Assemblies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973231.aspx)

Comment: @SteveWellens It's grey because she added it manually. She should try to re-add the class as a regular class and add code to the class to get VS to pick it up

Comment: @RyanTernier I tried adding folders manually and they weren't gray.  I also tried setting it to read only (since she got stuff out of source control) and it wasn't gray.  (I am on VS2013)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the file from the project.

Right click the project and select "Add new item..."

Select Class and name the new class ErrorLogger.

Paste in the existing code.

Comment: Nope, no joy. I'm stumped.

Comment: You said you created a new project but then added the files from source control.  That may have messed up the project file.   I would try creating a new project and then copying the files in not using source control.

Comment: Steve, I've done what you suggested by checking out the files from source control to a different folder from where my solution file is, then copying the app files using Windows Explorer, choosing Show All Files and then including the files in the project. I deleted all the source control-specific files before doing the copy. But I'm still not able to compile. However, today moving ErrorLogger to the root does work, so that's solved, but I'm also noticing that code behind files aren't seeing controls that are in the corresponding aspx file. ??

Comment: I just realized - there are no designer files, so that's the problem. Working on recreating them. This really shouldn't be this hard. But thanks for all your help.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know.

Answer (score 1):

I just found [this link](http://I%20just%20found%20[this%20link][2];%20I%20think%20it%20explains%20the%20behavior%20I'm%20seeing.%20It%20appears%20this%20was%20originally%20a%20Web%20Site%20Project%20NOT%20a%20Web%20Application.%20At%20any%20rate,%20as%20I%20noted%20in%20a%20comment%20below,%20I'm%20able%20to%20move%20the%20class%20files%20from%20the%20App_Code%20folder); I think it explains the behavior I'm seeing. It appears this was originally a Web Site Project NOT a Web Application. At any rate, as I noted in a comment above, I'm able to move the class files from the App_Code folder to the root and they compile fine. Thanks to everyone for their help!

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
using ErrorLogger;
```

reference in your page.

Comment: I've tried that, but the using statement gives me the same "the type or namespace..." error message.

Answer (score 0):

Add the folder to your using directives at the top of the implementing file, like so:

```
using AAT.App_Code;
```

Comment: When I try that, the App_Code portion of the line gives me the same "the type or namespace...." error message.

Comment: @Melanie that's because you don't appear to be using `namespace` both provided answers will not solve your issue..

Answer (score 0):

When you add the folder name App_Code, visual studio will treat the classes in this folder differently. The build action of the property of the classes is set as "Content". You need to click the property to change it as "Compile".